# EF core .any not filtering results

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following sql, which I'm trying to translate to linq:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Service] s
  inner join vendor  v on vendorid=v.id
  inner join VendorLocation vl on vl.VendorId=v.id
  where s.active=1 and v.active=1 and vl.City = 'toronto' and vl.Active=1
```

I have a Service that belongs to a Vendor and the Vendor has Locations.  I'm trying to filter the locations based on city, but the query returns results that don't satisfy the conditions in the ".Any" clause

```
 var service = await _context.Service
                .Where(s => s.Active && s.Vendor.Active)
                .Include(s => s.Vendor)
                    .ThenInclude(s => s.VendorLocations)
                         .Where(s => s.Vendor.VendorLocations.Any(l => l.City == City && l.Active))
                .ToListAsync();
```

The sql statement returns the correct results but the linq is not.
Any help is appreciated, thanks! Ben

Comment: `Any` does not filter locations, it filters the services. And filtered `Include`s are not  supported.

Comment: What is the result you're trying to achieve, and object composed with the three entities that meet the conditions?

Comment: Thanks, that explains why Locations is not being filtered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with query notation:

```
var query = from v in _context.Vendors 
            join s in v.Services on v.Id equals s.VendorId
            join l in v.ServiceLocations on v.Id equals l.VendorId
            where v.Active && s.Active && l.City=="Toronto"
            select new {v,s,l};

var result= await query.ToLinqAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your answer lead me down the right path.  In your example, S contains ServiceLocations but filtering is still not working, but L is filtered properly.  So I just using L together with S instead of v.ServiceLocations.  Solution isn't optimal but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your using **EF Core** now , But 
I suggest Use **LINQ** because its simplest 
Please read this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause) for more
and this is sample code

```
var innerGroupJoinQuery2 =
    from category in categories
    join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID into prodGroup
    from prod2 in prodGroup
    where prod2.UnitPrice > 2.50M
    select prod2;
```

Answer (score 0):

> the query returns results that don't satisfy the conditions in the ".Any" clause

Those queries just aren't the same.  The SQL Query returns one row per VendorLocation with additional columns from joined tables, and projects all the columns.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Service] s
  inner join vendor  v on vendorid=v.id
  inner join VendorLocation vl on vl.VendorId=v.id
  where s.active=1 and v.active=1 and vl.City = 'toronto' and vl.Active=1
```

In LINQ this would be something like

```
from vl in VendorLocation
where vl.Vendor.Active 
   && vl.Vendor.Service.Active 
   && vl.Active
   && vl.City = 'toronto'
select new
{
   ServiceName = vl.Vendor.Service.Name,
   ServiceDescription = vl.Vendor.Service.Description,
   . . .
   VendorName = vl.Vendor.Name, 
   VendorWhatever = vl.Vendor.Whatever, 
   . . .
   vl.Name,
   . . . 
};
```